# How can I check a column for NULL values in node-orm

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, orm

I'm using the orm package in node.js and I'm trying to query the database using `find()` on one of my models. However, I can't figure out how to check a column for NULL values using `find()`. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

If the sent_at field is not there when its not set then:

```
db.emails.find({sent_at: {$exists: false}})
```

If its there and null, or not there at all:

```
db.emails.find({sent_at: null})
```

**Reference:** [Query for nul fields](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-for-null-fields/)

**Note:** Since you didn't mention the database name nor the orm which you used assuming the database as mongodb.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

How about putting null in the condition

```
schema.find({ col: null}, function (err, people) {  …  });
```

or

```
schema.count({ col: null }, function (err, count) {
    console.log("We have %d Does in our db", count);
});
```

Documentation also says you can make **Raw queries**

```
db.driver.execQuery(
  "SELECT * FROM table WHERE col IS NOT NULL",
  function (err, data) { ... }
)
```